# Changing ./bin/sh from linking to dash to linking to bash

Tags: bash, unity-dash

For years I used Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstations, which link /bin/sh to bash. Ubuntu links /bin/sh to dash. Most of my scripts begin with "#! /bin/bash". A few don't; those are bugs. I have tried to fix them all but I may have missed some.

More importantly, there seem to be things in my environment that dash doesn't like. When at runs,an error message that I don't understand appears, though that seems to be at's only problem. However, there is a more serious problem with cron. It can't play sounds. That problem may well have nothing to do with dash, but I would like to eliminate that possibility. So my question is:

If I change /bin/sh from linking to dash to linking to bash, will that make ubuntu in any way unhappy?

Comment: I'd suggest adding `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the top of your crontabs before jumping to global changes to `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses [dash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dash.1.html) as an interpreter on many startup and core tasks. The main reason for this is to use a faster, less memory consuming and overall a more efficient interpreter than bash.

You can read more about dash in ubuntu (including developer-related issues) in [this wiki documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).

Regarding dash errors (also covered in the wiki above): not all command syntax supported by bash is also fully supported by dash. This may cause syntax and / or interpretation errors.

Changing the `/bin/sh` symlinc may cause unexpected results, and it is best to avoide doing so unless you are absolutely sure what you're doing.